# iis7.5 windows authentication prompt shows on remote clients

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication, ldap

I am building an Intranet system currently and the client has insisted on automatic login.

I have set up the system to authenticate the currently logged in (to windows) domain user in IIS 7.5 via Windows Authentication. 
The system than uses the user's username to drag details from AD via LDAP.

This works perfectly locally, however if a remote client (lets say a spare pc I have as a test-bed) which is on the same domain, and logged in as a spare test user, it will ask for login details via the standard prompt.

Once the user has done this, the system works fine, drags details from AD etc etc. but will ask again for login details the next time.

So the question is: Why is this happening? and how can I stop the prompt?

Is it something to do with the IIS user?
I have authentication mode="Windows" in web.config, and I do NOT have Impersonate enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably all you have to do is to add the site to the local intranet zone in IE.

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2012/06/iis-75-integrated-security-with-no.html

Comment: Ah now that makes sense.. I'll give it a go asap, do you know of any way to do this in chrome / firefox?

Comment: Nope. I was not able to setup this in Firefox, although the docs says it is supported. As for Chrome, I believe the integrated auth is still unsupported.